# Why would the ASP.NET MVC HttpFileCollection return an array of strings rather than a Collection of HttpPostedFile?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have an AngularJS + ASP.NET MVC 5 application where I am attempting to implement single file uploading.

On the client side I have the following code:

```
api.uploadFileV2 = function (alias, file, fnSuccess, fnError) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(file.name, file);
    $http.post('/api/V2/Upload/' + alias, formData, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    }).success(function (data) {
        if (fnSuccess)
            fnSuccess(data);
    }).error(function (data) {
        if (fnError)
            fnError(data);
    });
}
```

The file parameter is passed in from a function invoked by a button click and when executing in Chrome and in Edge I can see that the file parameter is in fact a file object.

Back on the server side I have a route to a controller defined as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "V2UploadApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/V2/Upload/{alias}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Upload", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Back on the server side I have my UploadController in which I have the following method defined:

```
public JArray Upload(string Alias)
{
    JArray results = new JArray();
    try
    {
        HttpRequest r = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        HttpFileCollection c = r.Files;
        foreach (var item in r.Files)
        {
            string theType = item.GetType().Name;
        }

    }
    ...
}
```

NOTE: The reason for the odd method signature with the Alias parameter is that ultimately the uploaded file will be managed by a Powershell script the selection and security level of which depends on the alias value.

Upon execution of the UploadController.Upload method I see the Alias value I'm expecting.

I do not see my file object.  So **var item** does not resolve to the type **HttpPostedFile** as I expect but instead it resolves to a **string type** and so the variable **"theType" contains "string" and not "HttpPostedFile"**.  The HttpFileCollection doesn't actually contain a collection of HttpPostedFile objects and attempting cast the items in the collection results to the type HttpPostedFile results in an exception being thrown.

What could be causing this bizarre behavior on the server side and what can I do o correct it?

Something as basic as uploading a file should not be this difficult so I must be missing something obvious - trouble is I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

So after another debugging session I altered the code to:

```
HttpRequest r = HttpContext.Current.Request;
HttpFileCollection c = r.Files;
foreach (string key in r.Files.Keys)
{
    var item = r.Files[key];
    string theType = item.GetType().Name;
}
```

This code not only works but also appeals to my old fashioned coding style of NOT lazily leaving absolutely everything up to the compiler using **var**.  I wrongly assumed the enumerator of the HttpFileCollection to return **(string)Key/(HttpPostedFile)Value** pairs but I was wrong.